# Does Yum support a drop directory for its configuration?

Tags: yum, oracle-linux

Some tools configuration supports drop directories to alter or append the configuration without changing the distributed configuration file, for example, `/etc/sudoers.d` and so on.

I wanted to know, does Yum support this? There is `/etc/yum.conf`, and there are repository drop directory, `/etc/yum.repos.d`, is there an equivalent like `yum.conf.d` intended to add things into its `[main]` section?

This should work in Oracle Linux 7.9, if this matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither `yum`, nor `dnf` support this unfortunately.

I've also been looking for this feature.

I've just filed a [feature request](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf/issues/1914) against dnf.